# Using multiple audio files in the same React app page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio, browser, media-player

I'm creating a Timer app.
I'd like to have a sound for two cases: timer starts or pauses.

When trying to import files as `new Audio` then playing them, I get this error:

`Blocked attempt to create a WebMediaPlayer as there are too many WebMediaPlayers already in existence. See crbug.com/1144736#c27`

The code itself:

```js
  const startSfx= new Audio(startPing)
  const pauseSfx = new Audio(pausePing)

  //...

  const pauseCycle = () => {
    //...
    pauseSfx.play()
  }

  const startCycle = () => {
    // ...
    startSfx.play()
  }

  // and so on...
```

Note that sound is **not meant to be controlled** but simply played on given events.

Everything is in vanilla ReactJS with zero dependencies.

Comment: Please try to create a similar scenario in jsfiddle

Comment: I copied everything, so it might not be like the simplified code I provided here on stack:
https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-panka-xhc84k?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Its working fine right? In what scenario error happens?

Comment: is it working for you? Because I get hundreds of errors and no sound is playing...

Comment: I'm using chrome by the way - don't know if it's browser-related

Comment: Its working fine for me, might be related to browser version

Comment: Chrome is fully updated for me - same error goes for Opera

Comment: I'll push this to a public repo on GH today, i'll C/C the link when it's done